# parse the Array and get the right data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sequelize.js, javascript-objects

I've an array which contains objects. I'm trying to access these objects in javascript but it throws up an error everytime.

Here's the array,

```
[ Provider {
    dataValues:
     { uuid: 'abc123',
       csgKey: 'aghzfmNzZ2FwaXIgICAoMSfCQyiAQhtZWRfc3VwcA',
       naic: '61239',
       name: 'Company',
       enabled: true,
       weight: 0,
       createdAt: Invalid Date,
       updatedAt: Invalid Date,
       ApplicationVersions: [Object] },
    _previousDataValues:
     { uuid: 'abc123',
       csgKey: 'hzQ29tcGFueRiAgICAoMSfCQyiAQhtZWRfc3VwcA',
       naic: '61239',
       name: 'Company',
       enabled: true,
       weight: 0,
       createdAt: Invalid Date,
       updatedAt: Invalid Date,
       ApplicationVersions: [Object] },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: true,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       underscoredAll: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: [Object],
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: [],
       hooks: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       classMethods: {},
       sequelize: [Object],
       uniqueKeys: [Object],
       hasPrimaryKeys: true },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: false,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       include: [Object],
       includeNames: [Object],
       includeMap: [Object],
       includeValidated: true,
       attributes: [Object],
       raw: true },
    hasPrimaryKeys: true,
    __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
    isNewRecord: false,
    ApplicationVersions: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Here's what i tried
console.log(provider.Provider.dataValues[0]);
and
console.log(provider.Provider.dataValues.name);

This array is inside a function

```
Provider.findAll({where: {enabled: 1},
        include: [{
                model: ApplicationVersion,
                where: {'active': true},
            }],
        }).then(function(provider) {
            console.log('success function');
            console.log(provider);
            // console.log(provider['Provider']['dataValues']['name']);
            console.log(provider.Provider.dataValues[0]);
            // console.log(provider.name);
        });
```

That's why i used provider.Provider.dataValues.name

I'm getting an error saying that dataValues is undefined.
I want to access the name attribute inside the dataValues.

Any suggestion is helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: If `provider` is an array then the first property must obviously be a number, not `Provider`.

Comment: The "array"you posted is not an array

Comment: Does `provider[0].dataValues.uuid` get what you expect it to?

Comment: @VinnieJames If it's not an array, how do i parse it the right way to get the data.

Comment: `dataValues` is also not an array, its an `object`, see Pats comment `provider[0].dataValues.uuid`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's throws an error when i use `provider[0].dataValues.uuid`. 
Here's the error
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataValues' of undefined

Comment: @EbenezerAnandArapally I think you may have messed something up when you copied the output of `console.log(provider)`, because right now it looks like `provider` is an array with a single `Provider` object, but it's only tagged that since it's an instance of `Provider`, not because it's a property name in what's currently displayed in that output.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `console.log(provider[0].dataValues.name);` This is working. Thank you @PatrickRoberts and @VinnieJames